# Jquery wrap content inside a separate div

Tags: jquery

Jquery dynamically creates an image using a function and return data from Json

```
$.each(rtndata, function(i, rtndata){
    var comment_thumb = rtndata.r_thumb;
    var member_image = rtndata.m_thumb;
    var member_name = rtndata.m_name;
    var member_comment = rtndata.m_comment;
    var date = rtndata.date;

   var img_comment_owner='http://domain.com/s/'+comment_thumb +'.jpg';
   var ico = $("<img width=\"32px\" />").attr('src', img_comment_owner);

   var img_member_owner='http://domain.com/s/'+member_image +'.jpg';
   var imo = $("<img width=\"32px\" />").attr('src', img_member_owner);

   $(".show_comment").show().append(img_comment_owner).append(member_name ).append(img_member_owner).append('<div style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">'+date+'</div><div style="margin-bottom:20px">'+member_comment+'</div>');
   })
```

Everything works properly. I need to put the contents of any of the comments within the "show_comment" div in a separate div.

Something like:

```
 <div class="show_comment">
 <div class="comment">img_comment_owner-1 member_name-1 date-1 member_comment-1</div>
 <div class="comment">img_comment_owner-2 member_name-2 date-2 member_comment-2</div>
 <div class="comment">img_comment_owner-3 member_name-3 date-3 member_comment-3</div>
 </div>
```

How can include the contents created using append in a separate div ("comment" in example) for each iteration of $.each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

Change:

```
$(".show_comment").show().append(img_comment_owner).append(member_name ).append(img_member_owner).append('<div style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">'+date+'</div><div style="margin-bottom:20px">'+member_comment+'</div>');
```

Into:

```
$(".show_comment").show();
$(".show_comment").append("<div class="comment"></div>");
$(".show_comment").find("div").last().append(img_comment_owner).append(member_name ).append(img_member_owner).append('<div style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">'+date+'</div><div style="margin-bottom:20px">'+member_comment+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ".eq()" method (http://api.jquery.com/eq/). For example...

```
jQuery(".comment").eq(0); //first .comment
jQuery(".comment").eq(1); //second .comment
```

So in your cause you could do:

```
$.each(rtndata, function(i, rtndata){
...
    jQuery(".comment").eq(i).html("html_content_here)";
}
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".comment").html("html_content_here)";` is the same then, I think using the `.eq()` function in a loop is not the right way of using that function.

Comment: I believe the scope of "this" within an $.each would be the current element of the array. So I don't think what you suggest would work properly. .eq() allows the script to pull in the first, second, third, etc match of ".comment"...